# Setting breakpoints in libraries e.g. Material components?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, kotlin, material-components-android

I just built a library (the [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) library) [from source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/building-from-source.md) and added the local Maven Repository to my project. I can now successfully do some laymans debugging by adding `Log` calls to the local source of the library.

Now I also want to set breakpoints in the source code of the library - how can I do that?
If I use `Android Studio` to open a class from the library, it displays the source code as read-only from the `material-1.2.0-sources.jar` file.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint that logs/evaluates arbitrary code by right clicking on the breakpoint and clicking on More... Alternatively use Ctrl+Shift+F8 to open the Breakpoints window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the file is read-only, one can still set breakpoints as usual and they are also used during a regular debug session.